# Marketing Cloud - Contacts vs Subscribers, and limits of

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, subscriber

I'm working on a Marketing Cloud implementation and am confused around the limit of Contacts associated with the customer's edition of Marketing Cloud.  The customer's "Contact" limit is 75,000.  Does this also mean that the customer is limited to 75,000 subscribers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the contract was signed for 75000 Contacts - and if this amount is exceeded, Salesforce will bill the client for extra.

Do note that the amount of Contacts does **not** equal the amount of Subscribers in `AllSubscribers` list. Contact in Marketing Cloud is a *sendable* record with a unique `ContactKey` identifier.

Meaning if you set up Marketing Cloud Connect and decide to synchronise Contacts, Leads and Users, then each of these will count as a billable Contact for an example.

Definitely read up on [Contact Definition and Count Determination](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&type=5) to avoid nasty surprises.

Answer (score 0):

can I follow-up on this topic: does a decrease in Account object number of contacts automatically reflects on the All Contacts total count (billable contacts)? For example, if we were introduce a new boolean rule that reduces the number of contacts on the Contact object from 2 million to 1 million, does this mean that All Contacts will automatically be refreshed to 1 million, or do we need to manually (via API) remove the one million contacts that were added initially?

My second question is does the total contact count includes contacts synced from the Account object as well, or is it only from Contact and Lead objects ? Thanks.

Thanks

Comment: To your second question, no, Account does not count towards your contact limits.  Only Contact and Lead objects (those that are realistically able to be contacted).

Comment: OK thanjs Mike. A side-quetion: if I would re-sync the Contact object again just to get the data for for import into a deletion data extension, would this result in duplicates or does SFMC recognise the same contact key and does de-duplication during sync ?